# Spring Cloud Contract: common repository for all microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I am working on a microservice architecture system. I would like to setup a common repository with all the contracts of our microservices, using a consumer driven approach. I am taking this sample as an example:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/2.1.x/samples/standalone/contracts

No problems setting up a test on the consumer side.

But while setting up the producer to get the contracts, I realized that the `contracts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` contains all the contacts of all producers in the contracts project. This sample project sample is simple and only contains one producer: `com.example:server`.

What happens when more producers contracts are added like `com.example:my-supe-service`? From what i understood, `contracts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` will contain all the contracts for both `server` and `my-super-service` applications.

Does it make sense all producers get all universe of contracts by the means of this jar? How can we restrict the installed contracts to be to the service in question? for instance `com.example:my-supe-service` only to see its respective contracts?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the producer will only get the contracts that match its own group-id:artifact-id. Thank you anyway :)